# How can i find the accurcy for time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, pandas, forecasting, arima

I have to work for the first time with time series and I have some question about this interesting field of  machine learning.

### What I have to do:

I should make a forecast for quantity for some special good in the future. I should predict, that this good is available e.g. in next week in our shop or not. My Methods are **Prophet** and **ARIMA** and fitting method by **ARIMA** is `bfgs`

### My Questions:

- 1- How can is find the accuracy of my forecasting? Does something like R2-Score for regression but for time series in scikit-learn?
- 2- Shall I calculate the accuracy with RMSE? I mean that should I first calculate the `MSE` and after that `sqrt(MSE)?`
- 3- If the answer of 2 is YES, how should be the RMSE for a good forecasting? Big or Small?
- 4- How can I compare the accuracy of both models together?
- 5- Which method is suitable for small data (400-800) univariable?

Comment: “Accuracy” is usually used when the variable is categorical. Is your time series categorical? Also, literal “accuracy” is frowned upon.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en